# Ncurses getnStr with existing base string

Tags: ncurses, curses

I have written a program that uses ncurses for the UI and the function `mvwgetnstr` to read in a string from a window. I want to allow users to make edits to the text they enter, so if they enter `foo` they can later go back and append `bar`. I cannot figure out how to do this with the curses API, the `getnstr` function only takes in a char buffer and length variable. Any ideas? I started making my own string input function, but it's difficult to keep everything constrained within the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want.  There are many possible ways to organize a program:

- [`getnstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html) reads the buffer from the standard screen (a window)
- The [`wgetnstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html) function accepts a buffer from a given window.  Using a separate window (or subwindow) reduces the problem of updates for the edited buffer interfering with other things on the screen.
- `getnstr` editing is crude.  If you use the [`form`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form.3x.html) library (which in turn uses ncurses), that allows you to do more than just append/remove characters from the end of the input buffer.
- write your own input-function, which can get complicated.  The [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) program does this.

The [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) might be helpful for reading and seeing how to build up a suitable input function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the projects you linked and see what will work best for me